# Why outputting menu items results in boolean output? (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

**ANSWER** - What finally worked was doing this:

```
$menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items(2);
foreach((array)$menuitems as $item) {
```

Just that code alone allowed me to get the nav-menu-items. To output the attributes I just did a call like this:

```
echo $item->url;
```

**QUESTION** -

I don't understand why my code:

```
<?php
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] );
    $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
?>

<nav>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <?php
            foreach( (array)$menuitems as $item ){
                var_dump($item);          
             } 
        ?>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Outputs this and only this:

> bool(false)

I would have understood the code above to output each item that's in the menu by the name of "main".

How can I accomplish this? Why am I getting this output?

Comment: Check if the values of these variables are what you expect them to be. `$menu->term_id`, and `$locations[$menu_name]`.

Comment: @DaveChen they're both null. in fact, if I `var_dump` locations after defining it, it returns `array(0) { } ` . I don't understand how I can simply access my main menu and iterate through each one correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it returns false, it means wp_get_nav_menu_items failed, most likely because there is no menu assigned to the "main" menu position, or "main" is not a menu position. please check the codex:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_items/

I'd suggest var_dump the result of $locations, and $menu, I think $locations[ $menu_name ] should get you the id of the menu already, so there is actually no need for the $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $menu_name ] ) call

Comment: What finally worked was getting the menu id and calling that function on the menu id. I'll edit my question with the answer. Thanks for your heads up!